# Maven Run Project

Tags: java, maven

Is there a Maven "phase" or "goal" to simply execute the main method of a Java class? I have a project that I'd like to test manually by simply doing something like "mvn run".

Answer (score 426, accepted):

See the [exec maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). You can run Java classes using:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main" [-Dexec.args="argument1"] ...
```

The invocation can be as simple as `mvn exec:java` if the plugin configuration is in your pom.xml. The plugin site on Mojohaus has a [more detailed example](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html).

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>argument1</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: this is how an answer should look like! reference + simple example + complex example. the simple example did the trick for me (no more config needed)

Comment: is there a newer version of this plugin (newer than 1.2.1?)

Comment: Yes, there's a newer version, so don't copy the fragment above 1-to-1 unless you want to use version 1.2.1
See http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html for the latest version
As of now it's 1.6.0

Comment: Thanks, would you also know how to run a main class if in submodule with dependencies in other modules ?

Comment: This does not actully run the main class

Answer (score 65):

### 1. Edit POM.xml

Add the following property in `pom.xml`. Make sure you use the fully qualified class name (i.e. with package name) which contains the `main` method:

```
<properties>
        <exec.mainClass>fully-qualified-class-name</exec.mainClass>
</properties>
```

### 2. Run Command

Now from the terminal, trigger the following command:

```
mvn clean compile exec:java
```

**NOTE** You can pass further arguments via `-Dexec.args="xxx"` flag.

Comment: Does this actually work? I've tried it as both: <exec.mainClass>${foo.bar.SomeMainClass}</exec.mainClass> and <exec.mainClass>foo.bar.SomeMainClass</exec.mainClass> and it doesn't work. Error is the same: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project newtrex: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

Comment: It works, you may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850956/maven-java-the-parameters-mainclass-for-goal-org-codehaus-mojoexec-maven-p) post

Comment: @NenadBulatovic : It works if you substitute ${foo.bar.SomeMainClass} with foo.bar.SomeMainClass -> without the $ or {  }

Comment: @NenadBulatovic the key is, add the @(myProjectId) after exec:java. To sum up: mvn clean compile exec:java@(myProjectId)

Answer (score 15):

The above mentioned answers are correct but I am simplifying it for noobs like me.Go to your project's pom file. Add a new property `exec.mainClass` and give its value as the class which contains your main method. For me it was `DriverClass` in `mainpkg`. Change it as per your project. 
[image]

Having done this navigate to the folder that contains your project's `pom.xml` and run this on the command prompt `mvn exec:java`. This should call the main method.

Answer (score 14):

No need to add new plugin in pom.xml. Just run this command

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main" | grep -Ev '(^\[|Download\w+:)'
```

See the [maven exec plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) for more usage.

Comment: Pass further arguments via `-Dexec.args="...arg..."`

Answer (score 6):

Give the [Exec Maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) a try

Answer (score 2):

`clean package exec:java -P Class_Containing_Main_Method` command is also an option if you have only one Main method(PSVM) in the project, with the following Maven Setup.

Don't forget to mention the class in the `<properties></properties>` section of `pom.xml` :

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.main.class>com.test.service.MainTester</java.main.class>
</properties>

<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
           <mainClass>${java.main.class}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[STS](https://spring.io/tools) Run Configuration along with above Maven Setup:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look right to me. Isn't -P for 'profile'? If you're specifying it on the command line why do you need to put it in the plugin properties?

Comment: @Rup Yes, `-P` is for profile. Shared this, as it is also an option of running Maven project.