# Maven Build Failure For JBoss AS 7 Hello world example

Tags: java, maven, jboss

Im trying to follow this tutorial:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Helloworld+quickstart

But getting build error when following the simple instructions to clean + build package:

> gert@gert-VirtualBox:~/workspace/jboss-eap-6.1.0.GA-quickstarts/helloworld$
>   mvn clean package [INFO] Scanning for projects... [ERROR] The build
>   could not read 1 project -> [Help 1] [ERROR]   [ERROR]   The project
>   org.jboss.as.quickstarts:jboss-as-helloworld:7.1.2-SNAPSHOT
>   (/home/gert/workspace/jboss-eap-6.1.0.GA-quickstarts/helloworld/pom.xml)
>   has 4 errors [ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find
>   org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.2.Final-redhat-3 in
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 68,
>   column 25 -> [Help 2]

I haven't edited the pom.xml file at all - shouldn't this just work?

I've googled it and came across this: https://community.jboss.org/message/762371#762371
But I don't seem to have a settings file anywhere?

Please, any help would be appreciated!

gvanto

POM FILE:

> http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
>       4.0.0
>
> ```
> <groupId>org.jboss.as.quickstarts</groupId>
> <artifactId>jboss-as-helloworld</artifactId>
> <version>7.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
> <packaging>war</packaging>
> <name>JBoss AS Quickstarts: Helloworld</name>
> <description>JBoss AS Quickstarts: Helloworld</description>
>
> <url>http://jboss.org/jbossas</url>
> <licenses>
>     <license>
>         <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
>         <distribution>repo</distribution>
>         <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
>     </license>
> </licenses>
>
> <properties>
>     <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
>         message: -->
>     <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
>         resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>
>     <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
>
>     <version.org.jboss.as.plugins.maven.plugin>7.3.Final</version.org.jboss.as.plugins.maven.plugin>
>
>     <!-- <version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0>3.0.2.Final</version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0>
> ```
>
> -->
>           
>           3.0.2.Final-redhat-3
>
> ```
>     <!-- other plugin versions -->
>     <version.compiler.plugin>2.3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
>     <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>
>
>     <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
>     <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
>     <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
> </properties>
>
> <dependencyManagement>
>     <dependencies>
>         <!-- Define the version of JBoss' Java EE 6 APIs we want to use -->
>         <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including
>             a Bill of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or
>             a collection) of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct
>             versions of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0 stack (you can
>             read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs). You can actually
>             use this stack with any version of JBoss AS that implements Java EE 6, not
>             just JBoss AS 7! -->
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
>             <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
>             <version>${version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0}</version>
>             <type>pom</type>
>             <scope>import</scope>
>         </dependency>
>     </dependencies>
> </dependencyManagement>
>
> <dependencies>
>
>     <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
>         <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
>         as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <!-- Import the Servlet API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>
> </dependencies>
>
> <build>
>     <!-- Set the name of the war, used as the context root when the app 
>         is deployed -->
>     <finalName>jboss-as-helloworld</finalName>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
>                 <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>         <!-- JBoss AS plugin to deploy war -->
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>${version.org.jboss.as.plugins.maven.plugin}</version>
>         </plugin>
>         <!-- Compiler plugin enforces Java 1.6 compatibility and activates 
>             annotation processors -->
>         <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
>                 <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
> ```

Answer (score 5):

OK, here's what fixed it:

Commented out this line in the pom.xml: (I thought this is a type of variable that gets automatically inserted/replaced by eclipse/something, turns out NO IT IS NOT):

```
<!--                 <version>${version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0}</version> -->
```

Replace with:

```
<version>3.0.2.Final</version>
```

It now builds and I can deploy it fine, thanks for the help Nishant!

Answer (score 5):

If you clone the quickstarts from the github repository, e.g.

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart.git --branch jdf-2.1.9.Final
```

See: http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/get-started/

then you will find a maven settings.xml file in the root directory (./jboss-as-quickstart/settings.xml)

For each example, run maven with that settings file:

```
cd jboss-as-quickstart
cd helloworld
mvn -s ..\settings.xml compile
```

See: http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/#configure-maven

Answer (score 3):

You might have to create one (see [this page](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for more details):

> There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:
>
> - The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
> - A user's install:  ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

But I feel the issue is with the version string of the dependency. Hardcode the version and try again:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Uncommenting the following line might work too:

```
<version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0>3.0.2.Final
    </version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0>
```

Comment: Thanks Nishant - any idea what I can possibly put in this settings.xml file to help resolve this issue? it seems that it can't find the jboss-javaee-6.0 artifact, but I can see it is here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjboss-javaee-6.0

Comment: @user446043 I think the problem is with a random string `3.0.2.Final-redhat-3` lying in your `pom.xml`. There is no artifact on the page with this version. Try the hardcoded version solution first.

Answer (score 1):

Removing of redHat "postfix" resolved the problem, just have actual jar name, instead of having redHat postfix.

Have below dependencies in your pom.xml, then it will build successfully.

```
     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SP4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```