# Unable to build JBoss Helloworld example

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I am trying my hand at JBoss - and I'm completely in the dark. I have set up the JBoss server on my HP laptop running Ubuntu 14.4. An instance of JBoss EAP 6.4.0 appears to start okay.

However, when I unpack JBoss's Quickstart examples [found here](http://www.jboss.org/quickstarts/eap/helloworld/) into ~/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.4.0.GA, go to the helloworld web app folder and try to deploy the example, I get the following bit of ugliness:

```
owen@owen-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC:~/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.4.0.GA/helloworld$ mvn clean install jboss-as:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.2.Final-redhat-15 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 67, column 25
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ line 80, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 88, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 95, column 21
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.jboss.quickstarts.eap:jboss-helloworld:6.4.0.GA (/home/owen/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.4.0.GA/helloworld/pom.xml) has 4 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.2.Final-redhat-15 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 67, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ line 80, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 88, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 95, column 21
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

As described above, there appears to be errors with local Maven repositories, but I'm new to Maven too. What does it all mean? How might I fix it so the example is deployed to my server?

As was suggested by @Tunaki in response to this question, I removed my ~/.m2 directory and entered "mvn -U clean install jboss-as:deploy". The result appears to be almost the same as above sans the stuff about resolution not being reattempted:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-6.0/3.0.2.Final-redhat-15/jboss-javaee-6.0-3.0.2.Final-redhat-15.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.2.Final-redhat-15 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) @ line 67, column 25
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ line 80, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 88, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 95, column 21
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.jboss.quickstarts.eap:jboss-helloworld:6.4.0.GA (/home/owen/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.4.0.GA/helloworld/pom.xml) has 4 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.2.Final-redhat-15 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) @ line 67, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ line 80, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 88, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 95, column 21
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Any help appreciated....

Comment: Shot in the dark: remove your m2 repo and retry with `mvn -U clean install jboss-as:deploy`.

Comment: @Tunaki same result sadly...

Comment: Not possible. `-U` flag forces Maven to redownload dependencies so it always solves the error "was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced" you are getting.

Comment: @Tunaki You appear to be right about the stuff about resolution not being reattempted, but everything else remains.

Comment: Please post the updated stacktrace.

Comment: Then I guess this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085259/maven-build-failure-for-jboss-as-7-hello-world-example

Comment: @Tunaki Well, it appears so. I did what the questioner said and although Maven appears to still be giving me some grief, it looks like this grief is coming from somewhere else. My question can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @Tunaki Although the advice helped me "fix" the immediacy of the problem, it taught me nothing of why this problem occurred and it taught me less of Maven in general. If these problems are going to persist, they are surely going to frustrate others. Hence, the problem aught to be addressed by the people who put these examples together.