# Run main class compiled with Maven from terminal

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have two main classes in my Maven based project (Spring Boot). I'm using `<start-class>` property in `pom.xml` to indicate the Spring Boot main class. The other one is a process that I need to run manually sometimes.

This is the project's structure:

- Project (`pom.xml` dir) is in `~/projects/coolproject`
- Packages (containing the classes) are under `~/projects/coolproject/src/main/java`
- Main class I want to execute manually is `~/projects/coolproject/src/main/java/com/company/Process.java`

After run `mvn package`, I want to run `Process.class`, but I'm getting `Could not find or load main class` error. I have tried this:

- From `~/projects/coolproject/src/main/java`, execute `java com.company.Process`
- From `~/projects/coolproject/src/main/java`, execute `java -cp . com.company.Process`
- From `~/projects/coolproject/src/main/java/com/company`, execute `java Process`
- From `~/projects/coolproject/`, execute `java -cp target/coolproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.company.Process`

with no success. How can I do it?

I have tried to run it using Maven Exec plugin. From `pom.xml`'s dir:

```
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.company.Process"
```

But it runs the other main class (Spring Boot's main class), instead. It's ignoring the `mainClass` param.

Comment: `java -cp target/project-version.jar com.company.Process`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks for your comment. Same error.

Comment: After `mvn package`, from `~/projects/coolproject/target/classes`, execute `java com.company.Process`?

Comment: @VeryLazyBoy yessss, thank you! That did something else. Now, I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError, because I'm using some external libraries (declared in pom.xml).

Comment: @Héctor, then you'd better use mvn to help you resolve the dependencies. I think there is [something wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27324967/6845273) between spring boot and mvnexec. You can have a try with `mvn exec:java -Dstart-class=com.company.Process`

Comment: It works! using start-class argument works like a charm. Thank you very much! Post it as answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, while using spring boot, you should use `start-class` instead of `mainClass` as the parameter in exec plugin. Try:

```
mvn exec:java -Dstart-class=com.company.Process
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `java -cp` to run your main class, you need to pass the correct dependencies. It seems that `coolproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` isn't built with dependencies that `com.company.Process` needs. To build a jar with all dependencies, you can use [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html). Then you can try:

```
mvn package

java -cp target/coolproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.mycompany.Process
```