# Running an Eclipse Java Maven project from a Windows (DOS) shell

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

**Summary:** How to run an Eclipse Java Maven Project outside of Eclipse

**Details:**

I am a Maven newbie and I have created a very simple Maven project in Eclipse.

The Package Explorer view of my project is as follows:

[image]
The source code for the two simple Java files is as follows:

```
package Pkg01;

public class Calculator
{
  public double add(double number1, double number2)
  {
    return number1 + number2;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

      System.out.println(calculator.add(100, 200));
  }
}
```

and

```
package Pkg01;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestCalculator extends TestCase
{
  public void testAdd()
  {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    double result = calculator.add(10, 50);
    assertEquals(60, result, 0);
  }
}
```

From within Eclipse I am able to run the Java Application, the Junit Test and the Maven test, without any issues.

My question is how can I invoke the `mvn` command from the DOS shell so that I can:

1. Run the Java Application
2. Run the Junit Test
3. Run the Maven test

BTW running `mvn exec:java` from the parent directory of the project **is not** executing the Java application for me.

My `pom.xml` file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.newbie</groupId>
  <artifactId>Stackoverflow</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Stackoverflow</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

`mvn exec:java` gives the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< org.newbie:Stackoverflow >----------------------
[INFO] Building Stackoverflow 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ Stackoverflow ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.957 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-05T22:47:00-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project Stackoverflow: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

---

**Here are the reasons why I feel that my question is [not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850956).**

I created a very simple project with maven-archetype-quickstart and my environment is correct because everything {i.e. (1) Run the Java Application, (2) Run the Junit Test and (3) Run the Maven test} works for me within the Eclipse IDE environment.  The other poster was having trouble executing, **which I don’t.**

The comments that the other poster received were mainly for fixing his environment to get it running.  I don't have that issue since, as already mentioned, everything works for me within the Eclipse IDE environment.

All I am asking is what I need to do get the following things working from the command shell:

1. Running the Java Application
2. Running the Junit Test
3. Running the Maven test

Comment: Does your `pom.xml` include the `mainClass` and related elements configuring the `exec-maven-plugin` plug-in so that it knows what class to run?

Comment: can you post the contents of your pom.xml and .classpath?

Comment: When you run `mvn exec:java`, what do you see? Post whatever message you get.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include `pom.xml` as well as the error I encounter when I execute  `mvn exec:java`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven & Java: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850956/maven-java-the-parameters-mainclass-for-goal-org-codehaus-mojoexec-maven-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states `parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin`.If you look at the [exec:java](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) documentation the required parameter is `mainClass`

I don't see exec-maven-plugin being configured in your pom.xml so you could  execute Java programs using below command

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"`

Make sure you have compiled you code either using `mvn compile` or `mvn install` command before running `mvn exec..` command

```
C:\data\development\app_code\my-app>mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.app.App"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ my-app ---
300.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.960 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-06T09:55:23+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/116M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Sachin\data\development\app_code\test-maven\my-app>
```

For Junit testing you could call `mvn test` which would give you the test results status similar to your Eclipse IDE

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.mycompany.app.AppTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.099 sec

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.198 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-06T09:55:58+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/160M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I do see the same details being mentioned in the link by Karthikeyan Vaithilingam

**Reference**:

https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html

---

**OP Addendum**
You have provided the solution for:
1. Running the Java Application
3. Running the Maven test

From the IDE I can also invoke:
2. Running the Junit Test

Admittedly this is very similar to `3. Running the Maven test` but the output looks different.

[image]

Is there a way to do that from outside of the IDE environment?