# Invoking the Exec Maven Plugin goal exec:java from any directory

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I have been able to [run an Eclipse Java Maven project from a Windows shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723288/running-an-eclipse-java-maven-project-from-a-windows-dos-shell).  However, I am able to do so only by invoking `mvn` from the parent directory of the Maven project.

Is it possible to invoke `mvn` from any directory?  In other words, are there any command line arguments `mvn` supports that would allow invocation from any directory?  I am not able to gather this from the [mvn manual page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/mvn/).

Comment: First the page for the plugin is this: https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/ apart from that both goals like [exec](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) as well as [java](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) require a maven project. The question is why would like to do that? and more interesting for what purpose?

Comment: @khmarbaise Now that I have learned how to use `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="»Nested Package Name«.»Class Name«" -Dexec.args="»Command Line Arguments«"` as the command to execute Java code outside of the Eclipse IDE, the question naturally arises whether `mvn` can be executed from any directory, with the directory housing the project provided as a command line argument.  That will obviate the need for multiple **cd** commands if the Java programs are executed in a batch mode.

Comment: If you want to execute java programms I would suggest to create self running artifacts instead of using maven to execute a program...

Comment: Could you kindly provide pointers for creating **self running artifacts** from the Eclipse IDE?