# What options are available to mimic "sbt run" in Maven?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

In a project where I use the **scala** language, with **sbt** can launch directly from the terminal the command:

```
sbt run
```

Now I switched to use **java** with **maven**. If I try to run in the terminal:

```
mvn run
```

the command does not work. The error is:

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "run" ...
```

There is an alternative way to do it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project

Comment: So there is exec-maven-plugin.Ok, thank you!

Comment: You don't have to switch to maven when developing in Java. sbt can do the job very well. Just place your `.java` files under `src/main/java` and give `run` a go! You don't even have to have `build.sbt` in a project to use sbt provided the project follows the standard project structure with `src/main/{scala|java}`.

Comment: wow.. great! I thought that sbt ​​is used only with scala. this is very useful! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the [maven exec plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main" [-Dexec.args="argument1"] ...`

You can configure the plugin in your `pom.xml` to set what the default main class and default arguments should be.