# Connecting Maven goals with a java -jar command in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

Currently, I am trying to learn how to use Maven properly. So I found a [Spring Boot Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) and there is the following command:

> mvn package && java -jar target/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar

This command works in the Windows Shell, but unfortunately, not in Eclipse (newest MARS version). How do I have to rewrite the goal to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out myself. There is a command, which includes both: the maven and the java command. It works for spring applications. I used

> spring-boot:run

as goal.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Spring Boot Maven Plugin Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html), there is a run goal that you can leverage to execute spring-boot programs.

For non spring boot programs, I would defer to the [usage of maven exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project).

The shell command in your question is pretty much confined to shell usage only; though I'm sure you can find a plugin for eclipse to run shell commands.