# How to run derby ij interactive SQL scripting tool with maven

Tags: java, database, maven, derby

I am using below maven dependencies for derby

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbynet</artifactId>
            <version>10.8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbytools</artifactId>
            <version>10.8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am able to run java code which connecting to derby and also able to fetch record from table in java code.

But I want to run "derby ij interactive SQL scripting tool", so please suggest me because I dont have any idea to run it in case of maven.

I know how how run it in case if we download derby.zip from directly from Apache site

Comment: When you say "run with maven", do you mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project#1089338

Answer (score 0):

I have the following dependencies in my pom:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.13.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derbytools -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbytools</artifactId>
    <version>10.13.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After a maven compile, which will download the dependencies, I run ij on my Unix system like that:

```
java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/derby/derbytools/10.13.1.1/derbytools-10.13.1.1.jar org.apache.derby.tools.ij
```

You can also run ij from your Java code:

```
static void derby(String jdbcUrl, String initScriptPath)
throws SQLException, UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
    org.apache.derby.tools.ij.runScript(conn, new FileInputStream(initScriptPath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(), System.out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
}
```

If you use the interactive ij tool frequently, you might put the path to the derbytools jar in your CLASSPATH. It might by a good idea in that case, to make a derby installation at /usr/local or somewhere the like. That way, you would not be dependent on the way how maven stores the dependencies.