# scala main method execution from command line in maven project

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

I am new to scala. Any help will be much appreciated.
I have created a maven project having scala files in a package in ScalaIDE editor. I want to execute main method implemented as mentioned below in one of the scala file lets say TestHelloWorld.scala

```
    object TestHelloWorld {  
        def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {  
            println("hey .. Hello world !!!")  
        }
    }
```

I can run it from eclipse run as scala application and print statement be there on eclipse console. But I do not want to run it from IDE.
Please tell me, how should I be running this from command line in a general way, so that it gets executed?
People have suggested to run it through scala prompt "scala > ",  but I want to run it from normal console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Run Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project)

Comment: Instead using maven I would suggest you to have a look at SBT. It has a really nice Scala integreation

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for your response