# How do I run a single class after compiling the whole project with maven in command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath, junit4

I was able to run this in Eclipse but have problem running it with command line.

My main java class that I want to run is *Example.java* (inside *src/main/java/examples*) 
Note that although there is a simple junit test in the main Example.java I don’t want to have any tests associated with the java file in src/test/java )

First I *cd* to the directory where *pom.xml*  is

*cd pathToTheProject/projectname*

I do the following:

*mvn clean*
*mvn compile* 
*mvn package*

Now to only run the main class called  *Example.class* I write the following (I suppose *pathToMavenLib/.m2/repository/** contains all the jar files needed):

*java -cp "pathToMavenLib/.m2/repository/*" examples.Example*

But this gives me error: *Error: Could not find or load main class examples.Example*

Edit:
I solve my problem using *mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore" -Dexec.arguments="examples.Example"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a deployable artifact as war file (By changing packaging to war using    `<packaging>war</packaging>`) that will contain all the dependent jar files under its lib directory.
You can then run: `mvn clean install`

You can then extract it and run your class file directly by giving class-path parameter.

Other option is to use maven run plugin - 
`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main" [-Dexec.args="argument1"] ...`

reference: [Maven Run Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My main class doesn't have main method since it runs with junit. Do you know how do I refer to the main method in junit while using "mvn exec:java" command so I say something like mvn exec:java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore -Dexec.mainClass="examples.Example" but it gives me error

Comment: mvn -Dtest=TestCircle test

Comment: thanks, now based on the main java class I provided in my question I tried to run 
mvn -Dtest=examples.Example testUnsatisfiableClasses
but doesn't work. the command I wrote is true?

Comment: What is the error you get when you run it? Check your maven version and test plugin. Refer: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html
https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-run-unit-test-with-maven/

Comment: @april you are asking for trouble if you do not have a main method.

Comment: I solve the problem using mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore" -Dexec.arguments="examples.Example" thanks for your help