# Deploying and running Maven project outside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a Maven Project in Eclipse (Oxygen) and I can successfully run its code inside Eclipse. The project's source code also resides in a Git repository.

I would now like to deploy the project on another host (without Eclipse) with all its dependencies and run it there. I assume this is done by running a combination of `git clone`, `mvn install`, and `java`.

What are the exact steps I have to follow in a case like this?

Comment: You use maven in eclipse so what is the `mvn` command there?

Comment: @rookie you can create a `war` file using `mvn install` and then paste it inside tomcat and start the tomcat.

Comment: Thx, but mine is a plain Java application (not web application). See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following now works for me (`mvn exec:java` courtesy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project) previous answer):

```
# host runs Debian 8.9
apt install openjdk-8-jdk
apt install maven

# run as Java application
git clone <git-repository>
mvn clean install 
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="<main-class>"
```

Comment: I would certainly hope you're packaging this into a jar, which could just be run via the system's `java` command.

Comment: @Powerlord Maven creates a jar with my core classes as part of `mvn install`. The challenge is with all the project's other dependencies. Copying them into a single jar as well would be a hazzle, which Maven helps to avoid (at least to my current understanding).

Comment: You should take a look at the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html), which creates what is otherwise known as an "uberjar" which packages all your dependencies into it.