# Main class execution maven or java command

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a simple java main class and can execute it using the below command on server
java com.....MainClass

Now we are trying to use Maven in our application.

I am seeing on web that the maven command to execute java program is 
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com......MainClass

Can I still use regular java command or do I have to use the maven command exec:java?

It's not clear to me when to use the maven exec:java command.

Please help me understand when to use regular java command and when to use the maven exec:java command. 
when I use Maven can I still execute program using regular java command.

Answer (score 1):

## Maven

According to https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html Maven's objectives are

- Making the build process easy
- Providing a uniform build system
- Providing quality project information
- Providing guidelines for best practices development
- Allowing transparent migration to new features

So, you should use Maven for building your project... like [building a JAR package with main class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/2158271).

## Running JAR packaged main class

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1238173/2158271) or [this Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html) for running a JAR packaged Java class.

You can also [use Maven for running the main class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089338/2158271) but you should not make your production environment depended on Maven.

Answer (score 1):

maven is mainly a dependency mangement and a build tool.

u can still use java command to run your main class from the jar generated by maven under the target folder of your project.

java -cp "yourProject/target/folder-containing-dependenc-jars-if-exist/*:yourProject/target/thejar.jar" package.mainClass

ps: use the ":" separator on linux system , if you are under windows use ";"