# How can I pass a command line argument to the execution of a Maven program?

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I am working in Eclipse.

My Maven program has a pom.xml file with the exec plugin :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.exec.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>
            <argument>src/test/resources/file.txt</argument>
        </arguments>
        <executable>mvn</executable>
        <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I've attempted to pass an argument, but I continue to get the error:

> Unknown lifecycle phase ".\src\test\resources\file.txt". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

I have also tried to pass the file via the command line arguments found in Eclipse via Run As -> Run Configurations. I receive the same error message.

How can I pass an input file argument to the application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Run Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project)

Comment: @Joe I've consulted that post. I'm still getting the error message.

Comment: Are you trying to run `mvn` from inside maven? It looks like the effective command you are trying to run is `mvn .\src\test\resources\file.txt`, and that's not a valid mvn command line. What exactly are you trying to run?

Comment: I'm trying to execute the program. How do I do that? Inside the Eclipse run options, I have the goal exec:exec

Comment: That example uses `exec:java` to run `mainClass`, but you're using `exec:exec` to run an `executable`; copy it more closely to avoid that error.

Comment: @Joe Your comment made me realize the difference between exec:exec and exec:java. In my case I do indeed want exec:java. I changed the goal in the Run Configurations to exec:java, and it worked. I was able to strip out the ```executable``` and ```executions``` tags from my pom.xml. It is now working. If you create an answer to this effect, I will mark it correct.

Comment: First question: Why would you like to execute maven within a Maven project?

Answer (score 0):

I just now ran into this same error while trying to run the [Getting Started](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse) tutorial from OpenJFX.io. The specific place I ran into trouble was in the section on configuring and running a modular MAVEN project, step 5 "Run the project". The instructions there are as follows:

> Click Run -> Run As -> Maven Build -> New launch configuration to
> create a new configuration. Name it hellofx, and add the required
> goals:
>
> `clean javafx:run`

I omitted this step, as I could not find the place to enter a goal. Running then generated the identical error.

I had overlooked that the run configuration has a field labeled "Goals". It is located on the "Main" tab, mid-screen. Once I entered the required text in this field, the "hellofx" tutorial ran without error.

If the "Goals" field does not show on your run configuration for the project, I am going to guess that it will appear if you create a new run configuration by selecting the "Maven build" option.

AFAIK, my Spring Tool Suite 4 is based on Eclipse, and the Maven aspects will be similar, allowing for version evolution over time.

Answer (score -1):

Add a configuration similar to the following to your POM:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            ...
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>maven</executable>
          <!-- optional -->
          <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-X</argument>
            <argument>myproject:dist</argument>
            ...
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```

[Source](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: Can you explain what about this is going to help? It's copy and pasted from the other thread that I've already seen.