# Maven dependency .jar file not found

Tags: java, maven, file, jar

I have a simple maven project where I have a simple class analyzing File encoding. I am using the juniversalchardet library from [Google juniversalchardet library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3) . In the pom.xml I added the dependency from link above. When I build the project with mvn clean install, everything looks fine. In the local repository I see tha universalchardet.jar file also. The class file in my project is also compiled without errors. But when I run my project .JAR i get an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/universalchardet/UniversalDetector
```

Here is my dependency:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.googlecode.juniversalchardet</groupId>
       <artifactId>juniversalchardet</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am not very familiar with Java - what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you running the jar file? You have to make sure the library is in the classpath.

Comment: When I look into the Java Build Path/Libraries/Maven Dependencies the file universalchardet.jar is listed there? You mean that or somehing else?

Comment: If you just execute a jar on command line with something like `java -jar ...`, then this jar will no nothing about its Maven dependencies.

Comment: I found the error! I didnt set the Classpath to the jar file in my bat file where I am executing the project .jar file.

Maybe another question: I want the universalchardet.jar automatically place in the lib folder. Without manually copying it. How to configure that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven Run Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html
where you mention your dependency jar in your manifest file : Class-Path: juniversalchardet.jar

Or 
Consider making your jar as uber jar, refer: [What is an uber jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar)