# I am getting this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat

Tags: java, maven, csv, command-prompt

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For some reason whenever I try to run my maven project I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.
```

But I checked my classpath, it's correct. I've checked my dependencies, they're correct.

I think it might be the command that is leading to the exception. How do you run a Maven project with an external jar in the classpath?

```
java -cp target/classes packageName
```

Is that correct?

Comment: You need to add `commons-csv` as a dependency.

Comment: Provide some more information, maybe your `pom.xml`

Comment: You will need `commons-lang3` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you run a maven project with an external jar in the classpath?

> ```
> java -cp target/classes packageName
> ```

Your classpaths need to include the JAR files for the libraries that your code depends on.  For example:

```
 java -cp target/classes:path/to/commons-csv-1.8.jar packageName
```

If commons-csv had runtime dependencies you would need to include the JAR files for them as well.  (But it doesn't ... according to its POM file.)

---

Alternatively, you could use `mvn exec:java ...` to run your application as described in this StackOverflow Q&A: [Maven Run Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project).