# How does exec.mainClass work without exec-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, exec-maven-plugin

I have a project that uses the MojoHaus [Exec Maven plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html) to run some Java code. Here's the `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.happycoding</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-vision-hello-world-standalone</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <properties>
    <mainClass>io.happycoding.vision.CloudVisionHelloWorld</mainClass>
    <exec.cleanupDaemonThreads>false</exec.cleanupDaemonThreads>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>
      <version>1.100.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This works fine, and I can run my code using this command:

```sh
mvn clean package exec:java
```

I understand that the `exec-maven-plugin` plugin, which is specified in the `plugins` tag, runs the code using the `mainClass` property.

I was surprised to find that this `pom.xml` also works:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.happycoding</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-vision-hello-world-standalone</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <properties>
    <exec.mainClass>io.happycoding.vision.CloudVisionHelloWorld</exec.mainClass>
    <exec.cleanupDaemonThreads>false</exec.cleanupDaemonThreads>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>
      <version>1.100.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This file specifies the `exec.mainClass` property, but does not specify any plugins. However, I can still run my code just fine with this same command:

```sh
mvn clean package exec:java
```

But I don't understand how Maven knows to run this command without any plugins specified.

Is the Exec Maven plugin somehow automatically installed in Maven by default? Or is `exec.mainClass` somehow setting a property used by a different default tool within Maven?

I tried reading the [official documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html), but I didn't see anything that mentions whether the plugin is included by default.

I've [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project) that I can also pass the `exec.mainClass` property in as a command line argument, but I still don't understand how Maven knows what to do with that without the plugin being explicitly defined.

I much prefer the shorter file, but I want to make sure I understand how it's working and that I'm not missing anything that's going to bite me later.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `exec:java`, you *are* specifying a plugin, specifically `exec-maven-plugin` (along with [the goal `java`](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html)). Other common plugins that are used by being explicitly identified on the command line rather than being attached to phases such as `clean` or `package` include `versions`, `dependency`, and `archetype` (this last of which doesn't even require a POM to be present, since it generally creates new ones).

Note that in your POM you don't attach `exec` to any phases (that plugin usually isn't); therefore your `plugin` entry serves only to provide configuration settings in the case you run the plugin explicitly from the command line, in your specific case equivalent to the `exec.mainClass` property.