# mvn fails to integrate dependency

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a minimal maven project using [fasterxml/jackson-databind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.15.0)

```java
package com.mycompany.app;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

class MyValue { public String name; public int age; }

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        try {
            // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // MyValue value = mapper.readValue("{\"name\":\"Bob\", \"age\":13}", MyValue.class);
            System.out.println( "Hello" );
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

When I compile and run *without* `jackson-databind` it's fine:

```
$ mvn package
$ java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App
Hello
```

When I add the dependency to `pom.xml`, I *see* that relevant jars are downloaded

```
< ... omitted for brevity ...>
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.13.0/jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar (1.5 MB at 3.0 MB/s)
< ... omitted for brevity ...>
```

But when I uncomment and try to use jackson-databind I get:

```
$ java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
```

Here is the `pom.xml` for completeness:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>my-app</name>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <jackson.version>2.13.0</jackson.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Maven does not put any dependency in the jar of your application, so you have to specify them on the command line (not only in the pom.xml) with `-cp` or [in the manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR_Manifest); the manifest can be [written automatically](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html) by Maven and it can also specify the [main class](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make) so you can avoid putting it on the command line.
In both cases you need external jars to run the application, this means that you have to distribute them with the application.

An anternative is to use the [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) that creates an "uber-jar" containing both the classes of your application and the ones of the libraries.

Yet another alternative, just for developers, is to use Maven also to run the application, through the [Exec Maven Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1089285/685806).

Finally, just for completeness, in applications based on Spring Boot (not your case), you can create a "fat jar" (a jar containing other jars) using the [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that jackson is not in the classpath, so it's not known by the jvm, it's not directly related to maven, but maven will help you to solve the problem, by using plugins.

You could just manually add the jackson jar files in your directory, then inyour classpath, but maven is here to help you, there are many solutions:

1. You get the jackson jars with maven and add it to your classpath: use the [dependency](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) plugin
2. You make an executable jar that uses the manifest to load the other jar and you also get separately the jars: use the [maven-jar plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html) + the [assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). You will have a directory with your jar and the dependencies jar
3. you can use a plugin that make an uberjar, Spring uses this technology: see [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io): you will have only one standalone jar that repackage your code and your dependencies.

My preferred technique for a standalone java application (without any framework) is using an executable jar (the solution 2.) , you will then run your application with:

```
java -jar myApplication.jar
```

Here is the pom configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>yourapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</java.mainClass>
    <dest>${project.basedir}</dest>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${java.mainClass}</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        <classpathPrefix/>
                        <useUniqueVersions>true</useUniqueVersions>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>/conf</Class-Path>
                        <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
                    </manifestEntries>
                    <manifestFile/>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

and the file assembly.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
<id>dist</id>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<formats>
   <format>dir</format>
   <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
        <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
        <includes>
            <include>conf.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/bin</directory>
        <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*</include>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>

<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

The jar plugin permit to specify your main class and your dependencies lib on execution. the main class is configured in my pom.xml in the "java.mainClass" property.

The assembly plugin will get all the dependencies of your project, and even package your application as a zip for redistribution.

You go in target/...dist/lib directory you will have all your jars. you run java-jar yourapp.jar from this directory.

There is a little scaffhold to make it work from scratch because we don't use any framework, the TLDR solution would just be to use spring boot from start.spring.io, or other tool as proposed in the other answer.